# How to execute method after removefromsuperview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I have a UIViewController (call it SubUIVC) that was loaded via my main UIViewController (call it MainUIVC) using my showNewView method and when I am done with the SubUIVC, I return to MainUIVC using my goBack method.

What I'd like to do is execute some code in MainUIVC once the goBack method is completed and my MainUIVC.view has been loaded.

Can anyone help me with doing this?  Below are the two methods I made reference to above.

```
-(void) showNewView:(UIViewController*)showView{    
UIView *currentView = self.view;

    // get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
    UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];    
    UIView *newView = showView.view; 

    // remove the current view and replace with newView
    [theWindow addSubview:newView];

    // set up an animation for the transition between the views
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:WIPE_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToNewView"];
}

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender{       
    UIView *currentView = self.view;

    // get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
    UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

    // remove the current view and replace with superview
    [currentView removeFromSuperview];

    // set up an animation for the transition between the views
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:WIPE_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToNewView"];
}
```

Comment: why dont u use persentModalView or incase of navigationController - pushViewController and write code in viewDidDisappear of SubUIVC. This would be ideal approach to show a view of viewController..!!

Comment: The code needs to be executed in MainUIVC since it's the manipulation of the view after the SubUIVC is done its work

Answer (score 1):

Have a BOOL property in the MainController than get's set by the goBack: function.

In the main controller's viewDidAppear:, check that BOOL to see if the view's just appeared as a result of goback: being called and do your thing.  Obviously you should then reset that flag.

Comment: I tried doing that but viewDidAppear doesn't seem to be invoked after a removefromsuperview.  I'm guessing that's because when you add a subview you're not really getting rid of the view, just adding on top of it and so when you remove the upper layer, the view doesn't "appear" like it does when it is first loaded.  Could be wrong about the semantics of that, but in essence it doesn't behave the way I would need it to.